# apache nifi - use different separators to process a text fie

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have a text file with following content

```
2020-10-19 12:12:00.001;alan;male;{"id":"255","val":"22","type":"1","location":"12530,95823","status":1}
2020-10-19 12:12:00.001;anna;female;{"id":"256","val":"12","type":"1","location":"12140,25630","status":2}
```

I want to convert this to a csv file,
first separate by ; and the last column need to be treated as a json object and extract its values. the output need to be like in the below

```
date,name,gender,id,val,type,location1,location2,status
2020-10-19 12:12:00.001,alan,male,255,22,1,12530,95823,1
2020-10-19 12:12:00.001;anna,female,256,12,1,12140,25630,2
```

I am a beginner in nifi and I want to figure out the processors and their configuration to do this convert process. I have tried ConvertRecord and could only separate the content by ; .
It is great help if anyone could suggest a way to do this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an easy task ! but interesting.

I hope the structure is not changing, eg: the json column get more attributes !

So i would do this:

1 - SplitText by line(one line) - remove header if any

2 - ExtractText (create an attribute called `body` with a value of `(?s)(^.*$)`)

3 - Update Attribute with two properties:

```
  csv = ${body:substringBefore(';{'):replace(';',',')}
   json = ${body:substringAfter(';{')}
```

4 - ReplaceText - and put `{${json}` as replacement value , Replacement Strategy : Always Replace

5 - EvaluateJson and extract all json attributes

6 - Attributestocsv with this def

```
csv,id,val,type,location,status
```

7 - mergecontent - add header (your col names), Delimiter Strategy = text and Demarcator Shift+Enter (newline)

Quite long walk and maybe not so optimal, you might wanna look into jolt for a better performance - but i ma lazy to think about a jolt spec :) .

I have the template for this - but i cannot loaded here as is to big and cannot use any file share service, so ?

Also if you have a mysql db on your hand , you cloud just load it as csv and use json_extract function

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.id") AS name
FROM table
```

Comment: Execute script - could be an option.

Comment: Sure- execute script with python code would maybe do it in one step, but you need the script, plus i tried to do in NiFi alone

Comment: I absolutely agree. and i'm the one who give you the point ;)

Comment: @Up_One thank you so much.It took me some time to learn and do the steps and after I did all the steps, It work like a charm. It completes all my requirements and give the expected final output. Thank you again.

Comment: @daggett I will study and try out execute script.thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: If the format of every line is always the same, you could do this with a GrokReader quite efficiently

Comment: @Sdairs - i like this idea - but writing Grok expression requires a PHD and a trip to the moon :) lol , joking - i find grok very hard to understand - bu thats me